# AWS The security token included in the request is expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-sts

We have few microservice's which get deployed on Ec2 instance properly and run fine.
But few of the pods inconsistently keep on getting "The security token included in the request is expired" error when connecting to DynamoDB and SNS. surprisingly the DB connections to Aurora don't seem to be a problem from the same microservice.

These pods face this issue for a few minutes and then again start working properly on their own.
Even if we restart the POD, it starts to work fine.

Things we have tried:

```
        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy(PredefinedRetryPolicies.DEFAULT_RETRY_CONDITION,
                PredefinedRetryPolicies.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_STRATEGY, MAX_RETRY_COUNT_AWS_TOKEN_EXPIRED, true);
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration().withRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

        return AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration).build();
```

Also, we are trying to retry the above block of code from exception catch block, to instantiate snsclient,  if snsClient.publish fails with token expiry error, assuming it will create new snsClient where the security token would be new, but that does not work either.

From AWS SDK documentation, the IAM roles in EC2 are used by instance metadata service to get new STS token using temporary credentials just before they expire. But at times this does not seem to be working.

Below are my queries:

1. What could be the issue?
2. How to debug if the call of instance meta data service to AWS is failing from my ec2 instance? cloud trail is not showing anything.
3. We sometimes face DNS resolver issue in our eco system, can this be the cause ? does ec2 instance meta data service also use DNS resolver to connect to AWS to get new STS token?

95% PODS work well, 5% PODS fail with this issue for few mins in a week.

Please suggest.

Comment: By "pods", do you mean you are running self-managed Kubernetes here?

Comment: Yes, we have self managed kubernetes .